# Comparing generic parameter type using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core

I want to get a method definition that accepts an `Action<T>` parameter using reflection. I'm using .NET core 1.1.

Since the class has two methods with the same name, I'm trying to check the type of the accepted parameters to make sure that I'm getting the correct method definition (and not the other overload), but the comparison does not seem to work.

Here is some code that shows this problem:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

class ReflectMe {
    public void SomeMethod<T>(Action<T> action) {
        action(default(T));
    }
    public T SomeMethod<T>() {
        return default(T);
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var reflectedMethod = typeof(ReflectMe).GetTypeInfo().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(m => m.Name == "SomeMethod" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
            .Where(m => {
                var parameters = m.GetParameters();
                if (parameters.Count() != 1) {
                    // this filters out the 1st method
                    return false;
                }
                var actionType = typeof(Action<>);
                var parameterType = parameters[0].ParameterType;
                if (parameterType == actionType) { 
                    // this is always false, even if in the debugger both
                    // types are displayed as System.Action`1[T]
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `parameterType` and `actionType` are not equal, yet when I check in the debugger they look identical.

Why is that comparison failing?

Comment: Did you debug? Do you get **two** methods? What **is** `parameterType` for each method?

Comment: Debugging I get two methods as expected, ans the parameterType is Action`1[T] for both. I updated the question.

Comment: Action<> != Action<T>, See Titans answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to instantiate the generic definition of `Action<T>` to use the generic argument of the method:

```
var methodTypeArg = m.GetGenericArguments().First();
var actionType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(methodTypeArg);
```

Note: I do not have .NET Core 1.1 handy right now, I hope the api is the same, but your problem would be the same in any .NET version.

The reason you need to call `MakeGenericType` becomes more obvious if you change the name of the generic argument to the method:

```
public void SomeMethod<TMethodArg>(Action<TMethodArg> action)
```

Then it becomes more obvious that `typeof(Action<>) != typeof(Action<TMethod>)`. You are comparing the generic definition of `Action<>` (which has it's on `T`) with an instantiation of that definition for the generic argument (`TMethod`) of the generic method `SomeMethod`

Comment: I thought `Action<T>` in the method definition and `Action<>` were actually the same. Provided that this works (thanks!) what's the need to call `MakeGenericType` with the generic argument type?

Comment: @PaoloTedesco I added a bit more explanation to the answer, hope things are more clear.. Basically typeof(Action<>) is the generic definition. Arguments are never of this type, they can only de typed to a instantiation of the definition, even if the instantiation is itself tied to another generic argument

Comment: I got it now, yes, it totally makes sense. Thanks again :)